# Javascript Multiple Div Toggle With a PHP Foreach

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a foreach that loops through and javascript that toggles days of the week and then a checkbox that toggles the times to - from. Although, if there are two of these the toggle only works for the top one.

I am trying to figure out how to have each toggle separate on each div. I think I need to use parent but im not too sure. Also this is an edit, so I need to have the values displayed on each one if selected.

```js
$('input[id="specificTime"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
         $("#specific_on").toggle();
  console.log(state); // true | false
});
$('#MonChecked').click(function() {
    $("#MonTimes").toggle(this.checked);
});
$('#TueChecked').click(function() {
    $("#TueTimes").toggle(this.checked);
});
$('#WedChecked').click(function() {
    $("#WedTimes").toggle(this.checked);
});
$('#ThuChecked').click(function() {
    $("#ThuTimes").toggle(this.checked);
});
$('#FriChecked').click(function() {
    $("#FriTimes").toggle(this.checked);
});
$('#SatChecked').click(function() {
    $("#SatTimes").toggle(this.checked);
});
$('#SunChecked').click(function() {
    $("#SunTimes").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" style="height:30px">
      <div class="col-md-3 topPadding">
       Specific Times
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9" style="height:30px">
       <!-- <input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-on-label="All Times" data-off-label="Specific Times" value="time" name="specificTime" data-size="small"> -->
       <input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" data-on-label="All Times" data-off-label="Specific Times" value="time" id="specificTime" name="specificTime" data-size="small">
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <hr>
    
    
     <div id="specific_on" style="display:none">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
    
        <?php foreach ($week_days as $day) {
          $sday = substr($day,0,3);
          ?>
    
    
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-1">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-sm" id="<?php echo $sday?>Checked" name="day[]" value="<?php echo $sday?>" data-size="small">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 topPadding">
         <?php echo ucfirst($day) ?>
         </div>
         <div id="<?php echo $sday?>Times" style="display:none;">
          <div class="col-md-2 topPadding2">
           <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker form-filter input-sm" id="timepicker" required readonly name="<?php echo $sday?>_time_from" placeholder="From">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 topPadding2">
           <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker form-filter input-sm" id="timepicker" required readonly name="<?php echo $sday?>_time_to" placeholder="To">
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       <?php } ?>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!-- End of specific_on -->
```

Comment: You cant use multiple `#ids`, instead, you should use `.classes`.

Comment: Yeah I just now changed it to classes

Comment: Then your need to change your functions to traverse the dom to find the div which you want to toggle. Then you will realise your only need a 1 function to toggle not 7. Refactoring is almost always the best part.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I need to toggle the days only if they select them,

Comment: What's the format of $weekdays? Just one or two dimensional array?

Comment: Simply changing them to classes won't fix it as what will happen is all classes will toggle. You need to traverse the dom something like `$(this).closest('.row').find('.times').toggle()`

Comment: $weekdays is multi, and hold days as key and value array('from', 'to')

Comment: Although thats not my worry, I know that foreach isnt right, im just trying to get the javascript loaded in each div separately, and I can do the rest myself.

Comment: Instead of doing `<div id="<?php echo $sday?>Times"..`, you should do `<div class="dayname <?php echo $sday?>"..`, then you can just do `$('.dayname').click(function(){ $(this).toggle();});`, saves a lot of code.